# The hair of my character gets left behind

Tags: rigging

I have downloaded a character from Mixamo and imported into Blender. I then deleted the armature and created a new armature so that I could use the Rigify addon. Everything works great except the hair is left behind. I'm sure I selected it when I parented the model to the armature. https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Zbv.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Go to modifiers section and rearrange your particles modifier. I mean place it before or after armature modifier. One of it should work. Hope that helps!

Comment: The hair is a mesh not a particle though